# How can I fit a tapered fork to a 1 1/8 semi-integrated/zero stack head tube?

Tags: fork, headset

I have a 2004 Giant VT frame with a zero stack / semi-integrated headset.  It currently takes a straight steerer threadless fork.

Is there any type of headset I can put on so I can fit a tapered fork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are products like the Cane Creek 40.EC44/40.Bottom Assembly [(Here's a press article on it and its kin, which should read first)](http://www.bikeradar.com/news/article/new-headset-allows-use-of-tapered-steerers-in-some-1-18in-head-tubes-25275/) which may work (I know its been installed successfully on some other Giant bikes, such as the Anthem, but not on your particular bike). Theres a lift of the front end by 5-10 mm, so its not a free lunch (aside from the cost of the unit and ancillaries). You should go to your LBS and test this actually works with this or a similar unit and the desired fork though, before you drop the money on it.